# HTML file creation with image

Tags: iphone, html, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I created an HTML file programmatically with images sources. The images are stored in the documents directory. The problem is that when I give the image source path as document directory path the images are not shown in Windows.

So, I choose the second option is to give only the image's name instead of whole path. Then it work well on Mac & Windows, but now images are not shown on the device's UIWebView.

Then I selected to open the HTML file in Safari insted of UIWebView, but the safari could not be opened because URL becomes NULL.

My code to open Safari is as follow:

> NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);
>
> ```
> NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/AccReport1.html",documentsDirectory];
> NSLog(@"urlStr :: %@",urlStr);
> NSURL *url1=[[NSURL alloc]init ];
> url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
> NSLog(@"url :: %@",url1);
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url1];
> ```

I want to mail the HTML file that contains images. And these HTML file and images are stored in document directory. I want to show this HTML file with images in windows browser, mac browser and iphone's safari.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simple way to solve your problem is to keep Images and HTML file in same directory and refer those images in HTML files just by name and if you put them in a folder then give the complete path.

Answer (score 0):

The images are not showing because the image path specified within the HTML code is not the documents directory path.

I suggest you might have to construct an html string and then subject the uiwebview to load that string

```
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\" %@/image.png  \"></img></body></html>",documentsDirectoryPath];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: if i try your option then it works fine but the images are not shown in windows html file because the document directory of simulator is not there.